# Implementing a button that only shows up when a checkbox is checked in another activity (android)

Tags: android, android-intent, checkbox, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

Need help/tips on how to implement a button that only shows up when a certain checkbox in another activity is checked.

For example:
In a choose your own adventure story app

Edit Fragment Activity: You can check a check box if you want a button in that fragment that chooses a choice randomly.

How do I make the button only pop up when this checkbox is checked?

Here is the randomChoice method that I created. Just need tips on the above. Thanks in advance.

```
    /**
 * This method takes in an Array list of choices. It returns a random story
 * fragment ID of a possible fragment that the current story fragment might
 * go to.
 * 
 * Example: If there is a fragment that has choices a,b,c, each of them
 * leading to different fragments through toGoToStoryFragmentID. This method
 * will then choose one of these possible choices at random and return that
 * fragment ID.
 * 
 * @param Choices
 *            An array list of choice objects containing all the possible
 *            choices of the fragment.
 * @return The next story fragment ID that the randomChoice chose out of the
 *         possible choices.
 */
public static int randomChoice(ArrayList<Choice> choices) {
int ChoiceListSize = choices.size();
Random rand = new Random();
int randomIndexNumber = rand.nextInt(ChoiceListSize);
Choice chosenChoice = choices.get(randomIndexNumber);
return chosenChoice.getStoryFragmentID();
```

Comment: where you able to find a solution for this, if you could share the answer it will be really useful

Answer (score 0):

You may use `SharedPreferences` or if your activites are directly connected via an `Intent` you can also pass a boolean value whether the checkbox is checked or not.

Try these links:

- [How to use SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)
- [How to pass values via Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)